# How to lineup form inputs in single row?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with three input boxes. 2/3 inputs are single line but the 3rd is a description field and by default I have it set at 10 rows. for some reason this 3rd box is not aligned with the other two. see screenshot below. How can I move the third input box down to match the other two?

[What my form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzssV.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. We don't debug images. Revise your post to add your code and make it very clear what outcome you're after.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align: top;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
textarea {
  vertical-align: top; 
}

/* Not important */
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Name:
  <input/>
</label>

<label>
  Subject:
  <input/>
</label>

<label>
  Description:
  <textarea></textarea>
</label>
```